# How does MongoDB access collecition variable in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I'm having trouble understanding how the line 
`return mongo_client[collection]` calls the mongo_client method using the collection variable.

I can create a new Solution class, which (as I understand) calls the initialize method and creates the @coll variable.  The @coll variable is created by calling self.collection.  In self.collection I return mongo_client[collection].  However, the mongo_client method does not accept any arguments.  And the method seems to be "hard coded" to use a specific URL.  How does the collection variable get to the mongo_client method?

```
  class Solution
  MONGO_URL='mongodb://localhost:27017'
  MONGO_DATABASE='test'
  RACE_COLLECTION='race1'

  # helper function to obtain connection to server and set connection to use specific DB
  # set environment variables MONGO_URL and MONGO_DATABASE to alternate values if not
  # using the default.
  def self.mongo_client
    url=ENV['MONGO_URL'] ||= MONGO_URL
    database=ENV['MONGO_DATABASE'] ||= MONGO_DATABASE 
    db = Mongo::Client.new(url)
    @@db=db.use(database)
  end

  # helper method to obtain collection used to make race results. set environment
  # variable RACE_COLLECTION to alternate value if not using the default.
  def self.collection
    collection=ENV['RACE_COLLECTION'] ||= RACE_COLLECTION
    return mongo_client[collection]
  end
def initialize
    @coll=self.class.collection
  end
```

Comment: The `mongo_client` and `collection` class methods sort of do accept arguments, they're just hidden in environment variables (`ENV['MONGO_URL']` and friends). Is that the source of your confusion?

Comment: I don't think so.  self.collection sets collection = 'race1'.  Then I'm calling and returning mongo_client('race1').  But the database (@@db) set up in mongo_client is Mongo::Client.new('test').use(MONGO_URL).  Right?  So how does the 'race1' database get loaded?  I don't see that anywhere in the mongo_client method.